# How do I check only one checkbox at a time in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am getting an array of 3 language option from API now, and I'm mapping them. Right now they showing perfectly fine but I want to check only one out of 3 at a time.
[image: 3 Languages]

Language component:

```
import React from 'react'

const Language = ({ languageLabel }) => {
    return (
      <div className="p-5">
        <form action="#" className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
          <label for={languageLabel}>{languageLabel}</label>
          <input
            id={languageLabel}
            type="checkbox"
            value={languageLabel}
            onChange={(e) => {
              console.log(e.target.value);
            }}
            className="rounded-full border focus:border-none"
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Language
```

Comment: Can you use input radio, if you want only one selection at a time.

Comment: @TusharShahi I can't. Having same problem with radio type too.

Comment: Have you given them a `name` attribute?

Comment: Can you provide a mini reproducible example? There are components in your code and that might help.

Comment: @TusharShahi Thanks. Actually I was also mapping form tag, that's why it wasn't working. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react'
      
const Language = ({ languageLabel, name }) => {
  return (
    <div className="p-5">
      <form action="#" className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
        <label for={languageLabel}>{languageLabel}</label>
        <input
          id={languageLabel}
          type="radio"
          value={languageLabel}
          name={name}
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e.target.value);
          }}
          className="rounded-full border focus:border-none"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Language
```

use `radio` instead of `checkbox` make sure pass same name while create component

Comment: I'm having same problem with radio

Comment: it should work , the `name` property as this answer mentioned shd do the trick !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample example ... and this should work same with yours

> Here the `name` is the main attribute to keep in mind

```js
class Thingy extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
       <label><input type="radio" value={number} name="gender" />{number}</label> 
);
    return (  
      <div>
      {listItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy/>,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```